# How to pass List as argument to object in Scala

Tags: scala

I have created object which takes list as argument but when I passed list to execute object,I get error.Please guide,code is as follows

```
object myobj {
    private var dateList  = List[String]()
    private val NPARAMS = 1

    private def parseArgs(args:Array[String]):Unit ={
        if(args.length < NPARAMS){
            println("Insufficient No of Parameters")
            System.exit(1)
        }
        var i = 0
        dateList = List(args(i))
    }
    // Some code...
}
```

Now executing object

```
val dateList =  ("2019-01-01","2019-01-02")

myobj.main(Array(dateList))
```

Error

```
dateList: (String, String) = (2019-01-01,2019-01-02)

<console>:37: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, String)
 required: String
       myobj.main(Array(dateList))
                        ^
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "How to pass List as argument to object" and "I have created object which takes list as argument"? Objects cannot take arguments. Only methods can.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `dateList` is a tuple. In scala the notation (TypeA, TypeB) as in your error message is a shorthand for scala.Tuple2[TypeA, TypeB].

What you want is an Array `Array("arg1", "arg2")`.

Comment: What my code does is it merges output generating from 2 arguments.When I pass list to method then it works but when I create Object and pass list then I get error as main method accepts array of strings,I also tried what you suggested but then it gives output for 1 argument only.

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal example. I am unable to follow what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean

```
val dateList =  Array("2019-01-01","2019-01-02")
myobj.main(dateList)
```

?